# Mysql Query - Multiple queries - Do they run concurrently (edit: consecutively) or simultaneously

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I've got a cron job that executes a php page.  The php page is just a few lines that run 3 different queries.

The point is to clear out a clone table, update it with all the new stuff from the main table, then do an update to that clone table.

The php page basically looks like this:

```
<?php
require_once('/path/to/my/db/connection/file'); 
@session_start();
mysql_select_db($database_db, $db);

$query1 = "DELETE from table2;"
$query1_run = mysql_query($query1);

$query2 = "INSERT INTO table2 (SELECT * FROM table1);"
$query2_run = mysql_query($query2);

$query3 = "UPDATE table2 (blah blah a bunch of update syntax here)"
$query3_run = mysql_query($query3);

?>
```

We're dealing with a very large database with several million rows, so each of these queries take a little time.

The first query runs quick, but the second and third take a minute and about 3 minutes each.

Here's my question:  Can I run all these things together on one page?  Will it wait for the first one to execute before continuing to the second query, then to the third?  Or do I need to break these into to 3 cron jobs and run them several minutes apart?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They run concurrently. Separate cron jobs would be messy

Comment: Thanks @KaiQing - I've used a single cron and it seems to work fine.  Do you want to answer the question so I can accept it?

Comment: Not to be nitpicky but don't "concurrently" and "simultaneously" mean the same thing (happening at the same time or in parallel)? I think the word you're looking for is "consecutively" instead of "concurrently"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question in your title "do they run concurrently or simultaneously" the answer is concurrently.

Having multiple crons would require them knowing whether or not a certain process is complete. That can get messy. Having this in one file is the way to go here. You may want to set max execution time to ensure the script doesn't time out. Find your php.ini file and look for this:
max_execution_time = xxx (seconds)

change that to something higher if you need to.
max_execution_time = 240 is 4 minuntes

You can also look into mysql transactions to commit the changes only if all processes complete.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html